# Encurtar condição que verifica se valor é um dentre vários possíveis

Tags: python, if

Existe algum jeito de encurtar o  `if a == 1 or a == 2 or a == 3` do código abaixo?

```python
a = int(input('Digite um número: '))

if a == 1 or a == 2 or a == 3:
    print('O Número digitado está entre 1 a 3')
else:
    print('O Número digitado não está entre 1 a 3')
```

Comment: Gabriel, leia como [Como dizer obrigado em respostas?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/605/137387), veja também [Como e por que aceitar uma resposta?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1078/137387)

Answer (score 4):

É possível fazer:

```
if 1 <= a <= 3:
```

Desta forma está dizendo que 1 tem que ser menor ou igual a `a` que por sua vez tem que ser menor ou igual a 3. Assim atinge os números que deseja.

Python permite essa forma de usar o operador de forma a aproveitar a comparação. Eu acho menos intuitivo na maioria das vezes, mas outras pessoas podem achar diferente. Eu acho que pode não compensar encurtar e deixar mais confuso. A maioria das pessoas se perdem para entender isso, até entende, mas demora mais.

A parte boa dele é que é rápido para executar, pode ser até mais rápido que a comparação original. Comparações contra sequências de números serão mais lentas. Dependendo do que faça se tiver mais números pode ficar mais longo.

```
a = 0
if 1 <= a <= 3:
    print("0")
a = 1
if 1 <= a <= 3:
    print("1")
a = 3
if 1 <= a <= 3:
    print("3")
a = 4
if 1 <= a <= 3:
    print("4")
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/Kekzj2). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/lsoyjxfm-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Syntax/MultipleComparisson.py).

Comment: Vlw! Obg pela ajuda!

Answer (score 4):

Você pode usar a palavra chave [`in`](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#keywords).
Use palavra chave `in`, em uma condição, para verificar se um sequência(lista, range, string) contém um determinado valor. Corresponde função [contains(a, b)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.contains) do módulo [operator](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#module-operator):

```
a = int(input('Digite um número: '))

#se estiver contido na lista
if a in [1, 2, 3]:
    print('O Número digitado está entre 1 a 3')
else:
    print('O Número digitado não está entre 1 a 3')
```

Se a faixa de valores for continua você pode ao invés de usar uma lista usar um [range](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#range):

```
a = int(input('Digite um número: '))

#se estiver contido entre 1 e 99
if a in range(1,100):
    print('O Número digitado está entre 1 a 99')
else:
    print('O Número digitado não está entre 1 a 99')
```

Comment: Vlw! Obg pela ajuda!