# Erro em IF dentro de expressão lambda. TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'str' and 'str'

Tags: python, syntax-error

Desejo converter os valores da coluna para True ou False.

Código:

```python
train = ['NK','AA','F9','MQ','EV','AA']
df = pd.DataFrame (train, columns = ['train'])
train= df['train'].apply(lambda x: 'True' if x == ('NK')|('F9')|('MQ')|('EV') else 'False')
```

Erro de retorno:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-19-ce0ab7f3b9fa> in <module>
----> 1 test = df['train'].apply(lambda x: 'True' if x == ('NK')|('F9')|('MQ')|('EV') else 'False')

~\Anaconda3\envs\k37\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py in apply(self, func, convert_dtype, args, **kwds)
   4210             else:
   4211                 values = self.astype(object)._values
-> 4212                 mapped = lib.map_infer(values, f, convert=convert_dtype)
   4213 
   4214         if len(mapped) and isinstance(mapped[0], Series):

pandas\_libs\lib.pyx in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer()

<ipython-input-19-ce0ab7f3b9fa> in <lambda>(x)
----> 1 test = df['train'].apply(lambda x: 'True' if x == ('NK')|('F9')|('MQ')|('EV') else 'False')

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'str' and 'str'
```

Comment: Para evitar discussões longas e improdutivas a conversa foi [movida para o chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132783/) e quem quiser ler ou complementar algo pode utilizar o link. Para entender que tipo de pergunta serve para o site e evitar fechamentos e negativações vale a pena ler [O que é o Stack Overflow](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7256/70) e o [Guia de sobrevivência](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8089/70). Ainda, há a [help] e o [FAQ da comunidade](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/699/70), que podem complementar no entendimento.

Answer (score 2):

### A LINGUAGEM PYTHON:

Se considerarmos apenas essa expressão lambda, sugerida como parte da solução, [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/539011/137387):

```
lambda x: 'True' if x in ['NK','F9','MQ','EV'] else 'False'
```

Como já expliquei [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/521669/como-comparar-v%C3%A1rios-termos-diferentes-de-maneira-simplificada-em-python/521678#521678) e [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/482565/encurtar-condi%C3%A7%C3%A3o-que-verifica-se-valor-%C3%A9-um-dentre-v%C3%A1rios-poss%C3%ADveis/482572#482572) o resultado dum teste de [pertinência](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/reference/expressions.html#membership-test-operations) é avaliado como `True` se e somente se um elemento `x` é um membro de uma coleção `s` e em caso contrário retorna `False`.
Assim sendo redundante pois aparentemente o código se resume apenas obter de um teste de pertinência [convertido numa string](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/functions.html#func-str), o que se resume a:

```
lambda x: str(x in ['NK','F9','MQ','EV'])
```

Ou apenas valores booleanos:

```
lambda x: x in ['NK','F9','MQ','EV']
```

### EVITE USAR DATAFRAME.APPLY() ou SERIES.APPLY()

<sup>Como sugestão [essa palestra](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nxWginnBklU) sobre ganho de performance com vetorização em Pandas e Numpy</sup>

O fato é que os métodos [`DataFrame.apply()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) e [pandas.Series.apply()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html) operam por loops e portanto são inerentemente lentos.
O uso do método `Series.apply()` é lento pois o Pandas não faz julgamentos sobre a natureza da função usada e que portanto aplica iterativamente a função usada a série conforme necessário.

Embora iterações forneçam uma utilidade maravilhosa, cada iteração sobre um elemento é essencialmente uma única etapa na rota por todos os elementos da coleção. Este processamento passo a passo é útil quando a ordem da operação é estritamente importante.

O processamento vetorizado, em contraste, pode ser aplicado quando a ordem de processamento não importa. Métodos NumPy e Pandas permitem a vetorização. A vetorização quase sempre funciona mais rápido, pois o tempo de execução é constante ou cresce em uma taxa muito mais lenta com um número maior de elementos.

Para deixar claro, muitas CPUs têm conjuntos de instruções "vetoriais" ou "SIMD" que aplicam a mesma operação simultaneamente a conjunto de dados. Então vetorização é o processo de reescrever uma ação iterativa de modo que, em vez de processar um elemento de uma coleção por vez sejam aproveitadas a operações "SIMD" para aplicar essa operação simultaneamente a vários elementos dessa coleção.

Então concluindo que o código oferecido na [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/539011/137387) não é adequado:

```
train = df['train'].apply(lambda x: 'True' if x in ['NK','F9','MQ','EV'] else 'False')
```

Seguramente o mesmo comportamento pode ser replicado de forma mais eficiente usando um abordagem vetorizada com o método [`Series.isin()`](http://pandas.Series.isin) que retorna uma série de booleanos indicando se cada elemento está contido dentro de uma coleção:

```
train = df['train'].isin(['NK','F9','MQ','EV'])
```

Answer (score -4):

O problema foi resolvido substituindo a construção `x == ('NK')|('F9')|('MQ')|('EV')` por `x in ['NK','F9','MQ','EV']`:

```
train = df['train'].apply(lambda x: 'True' if x in ['NK','F9','MQ','EV'] else 'False')
```