# Python - Incluir caractere em palavras importadas do excel

Tags: python

Como faço para incluir "-" um traço após a terceira letra das placas,"na coluna Placa". Isso nas placas existentes e também toda vez que outra placa for inserida na lista em nova linha (Coluna "Placa")? A

EXEMPLO: NKK-89346

```
import pandas as pd
xp = pd.read_excel("G:/pythonProject/estudos.py/carros.xlsx")

print(xp['Placa'])

Resultado:
0    NK462519
1    NKN00699
2    NKL48559
3    NKK89346
```

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Acho que esse código resolve seu problema...
Crie uma função para add '-' depois do terceiro caractere e depois aplique a função na coluna com a função aplly

```
def mod(placa):
    if placa[3] == '-':
        return placa
    else:
        inicio = placa[0:3]
        final = placa[3:]
        new_placa = y+'-'+z
        return new_placa

xp['Placa'] = xp['Placa'].apply(mod)
```

Comment: Acabei de encontrar a solução, mas se meu código não estiver correto usarei o seu:

qtd_linhas = xp['Placa'].count()
ix = 0
while ix < qtd_linhas:
        celula0 = xp.loc[ix, 'Placa']
        placax = (celula0)
        tamanho = (len(placax))
        inicio = placax[0:3]
        final = placax[3:tamanho]
        separacao = '-'
        juncao = ('{} {} {}'.format(inicio, separacao, final))
        juncao2 = juncao.replace(" ", "")  # Para remover espaços
        print(juncao2)
        ix = ix + 1

Comment: Tem que ter um verificação se a terceira letra não é igual a '-' pq senão cada vez que vc rodar este código vai add '-' na posição 3, ou seja vc tem 10 placas com '-' adiciona mais uma e as 10 placas que estão corretas vão ficar NKK--89346. Isso server para o código que o Augusto Vasques postou também.

Answer (score 1):

A propriedade [`pandas.Series.str`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.html) oferece métodos vetorizados para trabalho com strings.
Entre esses método encontra-se [`pandas.Series.str.slice_replace()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.slice_replace.html) que substitui uma fatia posicional de uma string por outro valor.
O método possui três parâmetros:

- **start int, opcional:** Posição de índice esquerda a ser usada para a fatia. Se não for especificado a fatia é ilimitada à esquerda, ou seja, fatia desde o início da string.
- **stop int, opcional:** Posição de índice direita a ser usada para a fatia. Se não for especificado a fatia é ilimitada à direita, ou seja, fatia até o final da string.
- **repl str, opcional:** String para substituição. Se não for especificado a região fatiada será substituída por uma string vazia.

Para para incluir um traço após a terceira letra basta estabelecer que a fatia a ser substituída inicia e termina no índice `3`:

```
import pandas as pd

s = pd.Series(["NK462519","NKN00699","NKL48559","NKK89346"])

print(s.str.slice_replace(3,3,"-"))
#0    NK4-62519
#1    NKN-00699
#2    NKL-48559
#3    NKK-89346
#dtype: object
```

Aplicado no seu exemplo:

```
import pandas as pd
xp = pd.read_excel("G:/pythonProject/estudos.py/carros.xlsx")

xp['Placa'] = xp['Placa'].str.slice_replace(3,3,"-")

print(xp['Placa'])
```

Como já disse uma vez em https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/539045/137387

> ### EVITE USAR DATAFRAME.APPLY() ou SERIES.APPLY()
>
> <sup>Como sugestão [essa palestra](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nxWginnBklU) sobre ganho de performance com
> vetorização em Pandas e Numpy</sup>
>
> O fato é que os métodos [`DataFrame.apply()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) e
> [pandas.Series.apply()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html) operam por loops e portanto são
> inerentemente lentos.    O uso do método `Series.apply()` é lento pois
> o Pandas não faz julgamentos sobre a natureza da função usada e que
> portanto aplica iterativamente a função usada a série conforme
> necessário.
>
> Embora iterações forneçam uma utilidade maravilhosa, cada iteração
> sobre um elemento é essencialmente uma única etapa na rota por todos
> os elementos da coleção. Este processamento passo a passo é útil
> quando a ordem da operação é estritamente importante.
>
> O processamento vetorizado, em contraste, pode ser aplicado quando a
> ordem de processamento não importa. Métodos NumPy e Pandas permitem a
> vetorização. A vetorização quase sempre funciona mais rápido, pois o
> tempo de execução é constante ou cresce em uma taxa muito mais lenta
> com um número maior de elementos.
>
> Para deixar claro, muitas CPUs têm conjuntos de instruções "vetoriais"
> ou "SIMD" que aplicam a mesma operação simultaneamente a conjunto de
> dados. Então vetorização é o processo de reescrever uma ação iterativa
> de modo que, em vez de processar um elemento de uma coleção por vez
> sejam aproveitadas a operações "SIMD" para aplicar essa operação
> simultaneamente a vários elementos dessa coleção.

Answer (score -3):

Acabei de encontrar a solução, mas se meu código não estiver correto usarei o seu:

```
qtd_linhas = xp['Placa'].count()
ix = 0
while ix < qtd_linhas:
        celula0 = xp.loc[ix, 'Placa']
        placax = (celula0)
        tamanho = (len(placax))
        inicio = placax[0:3]
        final = placax[3:tamanho]
        separacao = '-'
        juncao = ('{} {} {}'.format(inicio, separacao, final))
        juncao2 = juncao.replace(" ", "")  # Para remover espaços
        print(juncao2)
        ix = ix + 1
```